# File I/O exception doesn't thrown

Tags: c++, oop, exception, visual-studio-2012

i have this piece of code that trying to write into a log file.

```
Logger::Logger(void) //constructor
{
    try{
        log.open("lodg.txt", std::fstream::in); //Open existing file.
        this->writeLog("Logger started", Severity::INFO); //Add line to the log file,
    }catch(fstream::failure e)
    {
        cerr << "File I/O error." << endl;
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Now i know that in this case fstream::in will not create a file if it doesn't exist,
but the problem is, even though it doesn't create a new file, it doesn't throw any exception, and I'm able to "write" to file that doesn't exist, code like :
log << "Write somthing"; //Not throwing any exception.

Comment: So, read the manual? Try if(log)...

Comment: If statement will guarantee that no exception will be thrown (if(log.is_open()) doSomthing()), and i'm trying to figure out why i'm now seeing any I/O exceptions.

Comment: did you try to debug it?

Comment: It isn't ever going to throw an exception until you call the [exceptions() method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

By default streams don't throw exceptions (in most situations this is not what you want). But you can turn them on.

```
// Set the states you want the stream to throw on.
log.exceptions(std::ios::fail | std::ios::bad | std::ios::eof);
```

Note do this before you open the file so that you throw when you attempt to open.

---

Note: Usually you want to check for failures explicityl.

```
log.open("File");
if (!log) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open";
    // throw or fix error.
}
```